# Can we add sites to Migration List?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently, when voting to close, only one site appears in the Migration list.
[image]

Can we get StackOverflow listed here?

Answer (score 1):

I checked up on this a while back. Word then was, we can't really do much of anything with this as long as we're in Beta.

This also applies the other way; like from StackOverflow to here.

The below might be a moderator-only option. This is what I see.

[image]

Comment: Don't take it personally if I downvote this answer.. lol

Comment: We've only had maybe less than a handful of cases that would qualify to be booted off of here anyway - Microsoft Dependency Injection springs to mind. You're not seeing the same?

Comment: I just VTC'ed one on the front page talking about how to wipe branches clean out of Visual Studio.

Comment: Right. Ok. But there are enough VTC reasons that cover it anyway. Besides - OP on the question in question (see what I did there?) has not clarified yet, whether the clutter he seeks cleaning is also residual Sitecore items - which with TDS would be a challenge. And also make the question very much in scope.

Comment: Mark, I don't have that option, as you show.

Comment: Aight. Well I'm reserving judgment anyway, until OP clarifies the TDS element to the question. It is tagged TDS and GIT.